# How to sort only positive numbers from a list?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am trying to make a list of only sorted positive list when the user gives positive and negative integers in that list. For example, if the user gave "10 -7 4 39 -6 12 2" my program would only sort the positive numbers and give out '2 4 10 12 39'.
So far this is what my code looks like:

```
list = input().split()

positive_list = []

for i in range(list):
    if list[i] > 0:
        positive_list.append(list[i])
        i+=1
positive_list.sort()
print(positive_list)
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? What's your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several issues:

- you have a variable that's named the same as a basic type (`list`), which shadows the type; pick a better name
- `for i in range(my_list):` doesn't do what you think; you could do `for i in range(len(my_list)):`, but you can also just `for n in my_list:` and `n` will be every element in `my_list` in turn
- your user enters text, you'll need to turn those strings into integers before comparing them to other integers, using `int()`
- you do `for i ..` but also `i += 1` you don't need to increment the for-loop variable yourself.

Look into list comprehensions, they are perfect for what you're trying to do in a more complicated way, to construct `positive_list`.

Your solution could be as simple as:

```
print(sorted([int(x) for x in input().split() if int(x) > 0]))
```

But staying closer to what you were trying:

```
numbers = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
sorted_positive_numbers = sorted([x for x in numbers if x > 0])
print(sorted_positive_numbers)
```

If you insist on a `for`-loop instead of a list comprehension:

```
numbers = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
positive_numbers = []
for number in numbers:
    if number > 0:
        positive_numbers.append(number)
print(sorted(positive_numbers))
```

Comment: That was very helpful. Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome - if you no longer need an answer, please accept an answer using the checkmark, so others can find solutions and people will no longer look at the question to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Rename `list` to something other than that. `list` is a python keyword.
For example `list_new` or `list_temp`

My suggestion is to try it like this:

```py
positive_list = []
for num in listNew:
  if num > 0:
    positive_list.append(num)

positive_list.sort()
```

Comment: Yeah that was an oversight on my part. Thanks for the help